# How would you animate something so that it follows a curve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

If I have
`<div id="curve" style="position:relative; height:100px; width:100px; />`

How would I make it move on a curve? I've googled and everything but can't seem to find another example that would call two functions at once. This is the kind of code I would like, but doesn't work:

```
$('#curve').click(function () {
    $(this).animate(
        { 
            top: 400,
            left = $(this).left() + $(this).left()*$(this).left()
        },
        'slow',
        function() { $(this).animate( { left: 600 }, 'fast' ); }
    );
});
```

Even if that's not correct code, I believe animate only takes "destinations" for something to go to, so a dynamic destination wouldn't work I think. What am I looking for to make this work?

EDIT:: I'll definitely pick up that plugin, but I'm also wonder why this bit of code doesn't work as I'd expect it to.

Here's another attempt using a for loop and the delay method

```
$('#curve').click(function () {
    for (var i=0; i<400; i++ )
    {
        $(this).delay(1000);
        $(this).css( { top: i, left: i*1.5 } );
    }
});
```

Except it just instantly goes to that position, no delay or anything. so if it was starting at [0,0], as soon as I click it it teleports to [400,600]. Why doesn't the delay work?

Comment: I don't think there is delay function in jQuery, unless you use delay plugin...

Comment: be sure that you're using v1.4+ of jQuery

Comment: Try `$(this).delay(1000).css( { top: i, left: i*1.5 } );`

Comment: Well I guess it works. So instead of making it a loop, you've made it recursive. How often is recursion used in JS?

Comment: Ah cool. So it was just the +'px' part =/. And that is good to know with the recursion. Thanks for all the help and examples

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that this time, you have to recalculate animated curve part by part in js and then do it by moving by little parts (= you probably could find plugin OR you'll have to do all the math by yourself)

*Edit 2*: Previously added link was moved=> http://foxparker.wordpress.com/2009/09/22/bezier-curves-and-arcs-in-jquery/. Thanks, Zach.

*Edit 1*: this intrigued me, so I did little google research - just as I thought: plugin ready for use here: http://foxparker.wordpress.com/2009/09/22/bezier-curves-and-arcs-in-jquery/

Comment: Thanks for the link. It will be very useful, could you also look at my edit?

Comment: updated link: http://foxparker.wordpress.com/2009/09/22/bezier-curves-and-arcs-in-jquery/

Answer (score 16):

The [jQuery.path plugin](http://github.com/weepy/jquery.path) is what you want:

Example: animate along an arc

```
var arc_params = {
    center: [285,185],  
    radius: 100,    
    start: 30,
    end: 200,
    dir: -1
};

$("my_elem").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)});
```

Example: animate along a sine wave

```
var SineWave = function() {
    this.css = function(p) {
        var s = Math.sin(p*20);
        var x = 500 - p * 300;
        var y = s * 50 + 150;
        var o = ((s+2)/4+0.1);
        return {top: y + "px", left: x + "px", opacity: o};
    } 
};

$("my_elem").animate({path : new SineWave});
```

Comment: @philfreo, the jquery.path plugin no longer appears to work. Any idea on how else to do this?

Answer (score 12):

Here's a simple little library I wrote that allows arbitrary cubic Bézier curves for an animation path, and even calculates the rotation angle for you. (The library isn't polished or documented yet, but it shows how easy it is to stand on the shoulders of SVG's DOM even when you have no SVG elements in your page.)

http://phrogz.net/SVG/animation_on_a_curve.html

[image: Screenshot of website]

*You can either edit the code and watch the curve/animation change, or edit the curve and see the code update.*

In case my site is down, here's the relevant code for posterity:

```js
function CurveAnimator(from,to,c1,c2){
  this.path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','path');
  if (!c1) c1 = from;
  if (!c2) c2 = to;
  this.path.setAttribute('d','M'+from.join(',')+'C'+c1.join(',')+' '+c2.join(',')+' '+to.join(','));
  this.updatePath();
  CurveAnimator.lastCreated = this;
}
CurveAnimator.prototype.animate = function(duration,callback,delay){
  var curveAnim = this;
  // TODO: Use requestAnimationFrame if a delay isn't passed
  if (!delay) delay = 1/40;
  clearInterval(curveAnim.animTimer);
  var startTime = new Date;
  curveAnim.animTimer = setInterval(function(){
    var elapsed = ((new Date)-startTime)/1000;
    var percent = elapsed/duration;
    if (percent>=1){
      percent = 1;
      clearInterval(curveAnim.animTimer);
    }
    var p1 = curveAnim.pointAt(percent-0.01),
        p2 = curveAnim.pointAt(percent+0.01);
    callback(curveAnim.pointAt(percent),Math.atan2(p2.y-p1.y,p2.x-p1.x)*180/Math.PI);
  },delay*1000);
};
CurveAnimator.prototype.stop = function(){
  clearInterval(this.animTimer);
};
CurveAnimator.prototype.pointAt = function(percent){
  return this.path.getPointAtLength(this.len*percent);
};
CurveAnimator.prototype.updatePath = function(){
  this.len = this.path.getTotalLength();
};
CurveAnimator.prototype.setStart = function(x,y){
  var M = this.path.pathSegList.getItem(0);
  M.x = x; M.y = y;
  this.updatePath();
  return this;
};
CurveAnimator.prototype.setEnd = function(x,y){
  var C = this.path.pathSegList.getItem(1);
  C.x = x; C.y = y;
  this.updatePath();
  return this;
};
CurveAnimator.prototype.setStartDirection = function(x,y){
  var C = this.path.pathSegList.getItem(1);
  C.x1 = x; C.y1 = y;
  this.updatePath();
  return this;
};
CurveAnimator.prototype.setEndDirection = function(x,y){
  var C = this.path.pathSegList.getItem(1);
  C.x2 = x; C.y2 = y;
  this.updatePath();
  return this;
};
```

Comment: I'm confused: Can your library be used to animate along an bezier curve defined by bezierCurveTo or do you need to have an SVG path?

Comment: @Thomas The `CurveAnimator` constructor as shown above takes four points and creates a simple path for you. However, if you set the `.path` property of the animator to an SVG path with an arbitrary path (that does not have to be on the page) you can do what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Are you using jQuery 1.4?

```
$(this).animate({
    left: [500, 'easeInSine'],
    top: 500
});
```

You'll require the easing plugin for this to work: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js

E.g. http://jsbin.com/ofiye3/2

Answer (score 1):

There's a tiny script, just for animation which isn't in straight lines, called [pathAnimator](http://dropthebit.com/demos/pathAnimator/index.html)

It's very very small and super efficient. and you don't even need jQuery ;)