# jQuery and animating around a central point

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I would like to know the best way to animate an element in a circular motion around a central point?

I couldn't quite figure it out... :(

Thanks in advance.

Neuroflux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

easiest i can think of is:

1. make the central point position relative
2. make the animated element to be child of above
3. calculate the top, left using:
   math.sin(time * (angle /second)) * distance
   math.cos(....)

simple demo:

```
var elem = $('h1:eq(0)')
    .append('<span id="round" style="position:absolute;background-color:red;">&nbsp;</span>')
    .css('position','relative')
    .find('span#round');

var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){    
    ++i;  
    elem.css({'left': Math.sin(i * 0.02) * 100, 'top': Math.cos(i * 0.02) * 100});}, 100);
```

See it in action at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UzNCr/).

Comment: This is also really good, nice to have the animation without a complete plugin library. +1

Comment: Brock, thank you for add the jsfiddle link and content. Neurofluxation, glad it is useful to you.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [**jquery.path**](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path) plugin, and here is a [demo](http://weepy.github.com/jquery.path/).

(found it from another question: [How would you animate something so that it follows a curve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240052/how-would-you-animate-something-so-that-it-follows-a-curve))

Comment: Huh, the demo did not work in FF.  Get `$.path is undefined`.  This appears to be caused by nosniff Blocking in NoScript.

Comment: I would of accepted this, but the non-library/plugin version was more useful for my code. You still got a few votes up though! (Including from me).