# jQuery animating falling leaves from scratch

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Just wondered if anyone knew a way to animate leaves falling in the wind? I've seen it done here: http://www.webkit.org/blog-files/leaves/index.html But that's WebKit only.

My code so far is pretty basic animation stuff:

```
function runParticles() {
                    $('.theme-bg').prepend('<div class="particles" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 100%; background-image: url(images/particle1.png); z-index: 1; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 0px;"></div>');

                    var randParXa = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.theme-bg').width());
                    var randParXb = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.theme-bg').width());
                    var randParY = $('.theme-bg').height();
                    var randParSpd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2500 - 1550) + 1550);

                    $('.particles').css({'background-position':randParXa+'px 0px'});
                    $('.particles').animate({
                        'background-position':randParXb+'px '+randParY+'px',
                        'opacity':0.0
                    }, randParSpd, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                        runParticles();
                    });
                }
                runParticles();
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Urgh, more info needed (I guess, due to the Vote to close...?)
So, I want an element `<div>` to fall from the top of the browser and "float" from left to right as it falls.... Like a leaf or a feather.

At the moment, my animation just goes in straight lines.

Cheers again!

Comment: I should also note that the background-position animation is provided by: http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/jquery.backgroundPosition.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind (again!)

This answer helped me a treat: [How would you animate something so that it follows a curve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240052/how-would-you-animate-something-so-that-it-follows-a-curve)

alongside this code:

```
$(this).animate({
    left: [500, 'easeInSine'],
    top: 500
});
```