# Animate image on curve

Tags: jquery, kineticjs

I want to animate an image in curve and at the end of curve Image should rotate.
I tried with [.animate with a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233606/animate-with-a-curve) but it is generating error

> TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using canvas and kinetic js.Just include

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/5.0.1/kinetic.min.js"></script>`

Add below script to body

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  // set up stage,layer and quadratic-curve
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 350,
      height: 350
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  stage.add(layer);


   // vars related to the images
  var bone, dog;
  var boneScale = 1;
  var boneOffset = {
      x: -11,
      y: 0
  };
  var dogScale = 0.50;

  // vars related to the quadratic curve
  var qStart = {
      x: 115,
      y: 85
  };
  var qControl = {
      x: 155,
      y: 108
  };
  var qEnd = {
      x: 200,
      y: 88
  };
  var startXY = getQuadraticBezierXYatT(qStart, qControl, qEnd, 0, 00);
  var pathData = "M " + qStart.x + " " + qStart.y;
  pathData += " Q " + qControl.x + " " + qControl.y;
  pathData += " " + qEnd.x + " " + qEnd.y;

  // vars related to calculating points on the curve
  var T = 0;
  var TDirection = 1;


  // set up quadratic-curve
  var path = new Kinetic.Path({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      data: pathData,
      stroke: 'green',
      strokeWidth: 3,
  });
  layer.add(path);
  layer.draw();


  // load 2 images
  var loaded = 0;
  var boneImg = new Image();
  boneImg.onload = function () {
      loaded++;
      if (loaded == 2) {
          start();
      }
  }
  boneImg.src = "<%=asset_path 'flight.png'%>";
  var dogImg = new Image();
  dogImg.onload = function () {
      loaded++;
      if (loaded == 2) {
          start();
      }
  }
  dogImg.src = "<%=asset_path 'your-logo.png'%>";
  var circle0 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 100,
    y: 56,
    id: 'circle0',
    radius: 9,
    fill: 'yellow',
    stroke: 'white',
    strokeWidth: 0
  });
  layer.add(circle0);

  // create Kinetic.Images
  function start() {
      var pos = getQuadraticBezierXYatT(qStart, qControl, qEnd, 0.00);
      bone = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: pos.x + boneOffset.x,
          y: pos.y + boneOffset.y,
          id: 'bone',
          image: boneImg,
          width: boneImg.width * boneScale,
          height: boneImg.height * boneScale,
      });
      layer.add(bone);
      dog = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 30,
          y: 15,
          image: dogImg,
          width: 300,
          height: 90
      });
      layer.add(dog);
      layer.draw();

      animation.start();
  }

var imageObj = new Image({id: 'bone'});
imageObj.src = "<%=asset_path 'mirror_flight.png'%>";
var flight = new Image({id: 'flight'});
flight.src = "<%=asset_path 'flight.png'%>";
  // create animation along quadratic curve
  var animation = new Kinetic.Animation(function (frame) {

      var pos = getQuadraticBezierXYatT(qStart, qControl, qEnd, T / 150);
      pos.x += boneOffset.x;
      pos.y += boneOffset.y;
      bone.setPosition(pos);

      T += TDirection;
      if (T < 0 || T > 150) {
          TDirection *= -1;
          T += TDirection
          if (T==150) {
            layer.get('#circle0')[0].remove();
            layer.get('#bone')[0].setImage(imageObj);
            var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
              x: 221,
              y: 56,
              id: 'circle',
              radius: 9,
              fill: 'yellow',
              stroke: 'white',
              strokeWidth: 0
            });

            // add the shape to the layer
            layer.add(circle);


            sleep(1000);
            // layer.get('#circle')[0].remove();
          } else if(T==0){
            layer.get('#circle')[0].remove();
             var circle0 = new Kinetic.Circle({
              x: 100,
              y: 56,
              id: 'circle0',
              radius: 9,
              fill: 'yellow',
              stroke: 'black',
              strokeWidth: 0
            });
             layer.add(circle0);
            layer.get('#bone')[0].setImage(flight);
            sleep(1000);
          };
      }

  }, layer);

  // Calc an XY along a quadratic curve at interval T
  // T==0.00 at start of curve, T==1.00 at end of curve
  function getQuadraticBezierXYatT(startPt, controlPt, endPt, T) {
      var x = Math.pow(1 - T, 2) * startPt.x + 2 * (1 - T) * T * controlPt.x + Math.pow(T, 2) * endPt.x;
      var y = Math.pow(1 - T, 2) * startPt.y + 2 * (1 - T) * T * controlPt.y + Math.pow(T, 2) * endPt.y;
      return ({
          x: x,
          y: y
      });
  }
}

</script>
```

You can simply control the arc of curve from var qControl
just put your images in place of dogImg.src ,imageObj.src ,flight.src

**Note:** The imageObj and flight.src should be mirror images of each other

Comment: Thanks for your help it would be great if you can create a fiddle example.

Comment: yes I tried to make a fiddle demo but their is no option to upload my own image as for proper demo I require to show 2 mirror images with same size