# jQuery, animate along an arc

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, bezier

I'm really struggling to find a decent resource to help me develop what I need. I have used Google, Stack overflow and even searched Reddit. As, I have mentioned before, I am new to jQuery so i'm not clued up on all the lingo, nor methods and best practices.

I need to make an object (image) move in a curve motion when I click a button and then also be able to move back when I click the button again, so the image will move from point 1 to point 2, and then back to the original position. This curve motion should be positioned at the bottom of the browser window and be responsive.

Here is a crude example of the curve:

[image: curve image]

Eventually, there will be a few images that move when I click the button but for now I will be happy with just one working!.

**Please can someone point me to a useful resource/tutorial/plugin to help me achieve this?**

If, it helps, the image at the bottom of the screen will be a full width globe and the objects will be items in the sky moving around it (Just incase this makes any of you remember an implementation online of this)

Comment: See here: http://jqbezier.ericlesch.com/

Comment: I found this thread.

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240052/how-would-you-animate-something-so-that-it-follows-a-curve

Comment: @KenQ I also found that, It links to a page, which then also has a link to a demo - which is broken so i dismissed it.

Answer (score 0):

use the following plugin and follow the code
[[https://github.com/Mottie/Pathslider][1]](https://github.com/Mottie/Pathslider%5d%5b1%5d)
run this code and it will display an arc

```
<style>

#slider {


 background : #eee url();
  width      : 316px;
  height     : 91px;

}
```

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
  $("#slider").pathslider({
    points     : [ 8,83,75,-100,-75,-100,308,83 ],
    value      : 50,
    rotateGrip : true,
    tolerance  : 3,
    range      : 30,
    curve      : { width:4, color:"#333", cap:"round" }
  });
});
</script>
```

You can also visit its web

[Slider](http://mottie.github.io/Pathslider/builder.html)

Comment: This creates a 'slider' on drag. Not on click of a button and also, I don't want the curve lines.